# Create global helper / mixin Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using Swiper Element in a nuxt 3 project and would like to create a global plugin and call register(). I can't seem to get it to work. This used to be pretty easy in Nuxt 2.

```
plugins/swiper.ts

import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(register)
})
```

Now how do I call this method inside a page or component file? or have it auto imported and accessed globally?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to provide a helper on the NuxtApp instance, return it from the plugin under a provide key.

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    return {
          provide: {
               register: register
          }
    }
})
```

In another file you can use this:

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const { $register } = useNuxtApp()
</script>
```

For more details: [nuxt3 plugins docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#automatically-providing-helpers).